# Why is the loader continuously rotating when trying to create a new DocuSign developer account?

Tags: docusignapi

I am exploring your tool for my company. I am trying to create new developer account of DocuSign. After providing required information and when click submit, the loader keeps rotating. Could you please help me why this happing? I sharing a screenshot.

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtH5Q.png)
Could not create a new developer account.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're having this problem. Please try in an incognito window and turn off any ad blockers.

Also, someone in your company be experimenting with DocuSign's SSO feature:

1. They claimed your company domain (eg all email addresses ending with @company.com)
2. They set up SSO with an IdP (identity provider server)
3. They configured DocuSign's demo / developer system to not allow independent accounts from the claimed company domain. -- Allowing access only via the IdP.

Result: you're unable to create your own account on the demo/developer system. In this case either use a non-company personal email account as Inbar suggests, or find the person who configured SSO for the DocuSign demo system and ask them for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If Larry's suggestion does not work, try to use a personal email address instead of a company email address. If someone in your company already has a developer account, it's possible that you won't be able to create a new one for the same company from this page.